# How can I get the PHP filename by using "auto_append_file" config PHP file?

Tags: php

For example, I use `tail.php` with `auto_append_file` value in my php.ini:

```
<?php
echo __FILE__;
```

When I run `php xxx.php`, the output is "tail.php", but how can I get `xxx.php` in  `auto_append_file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this for tail.php

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
```

it should be the name of the "parent" script which implicitly required tail.php as a result of the 'auto_append_file' option.   `"SCRIPT_NAME"` is another option depending on your actual configuration - again relating to parent file - the one which did the including.